# A word for female bonding

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, analogy, portmanteau-words

A [*bromance*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bromance) is "a close but non-sexual relationship between two men". Is there an equivalent for women? IMO, [*sisterhood*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sisterhood) doesn't really fit.

Comment: 'bromance' is a pretty new neologism you know. frankly, 'male bonding' is only a couple decades old, and they both seem created to fill the missing lexical gap created by close friends assumed  more likely to be female.

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure what you're trying to say. In any event, _bromance_ sees quite a bit of use nowadays. Somebody (female) was telling me that there's no female equivalent because women don't "bond" as such. Hence my question :)

Comment: My point is many fold: you've mentioned a word, asking for counterpart. I think that word is particularly new so I don't think there is a good reason to expect an exact fit. Do you think French of German have translatable pairs? Exactly; this is a cultural artifact. Does BFF fit what you want? It's not explicitly gendered but I only ever hear it for females.

Comment: @Mitch It didn't necessarily have to be a portmanteau like _bromance_. It is also not a junk word as its requirement is quite valid. In any event, as you can see, an appropriate counterpart to _bromance_ does exist and going by Books (and if you excuse the false positives), [it appears to be seeing some use as well](http://tinyurl.com/womance). IMO, BFF is more of a teenager thing. I'm also unsure why people think that this is 'not constructive' or 'general reference' either ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Womance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Womance) is the word you are looking for.

There is allegedly [homance](http://schott.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/05/19/homance/) but I have never heard it in use.

Answer (score 5):

"A **[womance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Womance)** is a close but non-sexual relationship between two (or more) women, a form of homosocial intimacy. The word is the female equivalent of a *bromance*, being a portmanteau of the words woman and romance."

Someone had already suggested **[girlcrush](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110509204802AAiFbTL)**: *feelings of admiration and adoration which a straight girl has for another girl, without wanting to bang said girl. a nonsexual attraction, usually based on veneration at some level*.

[UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=girlcrush) defines *girlcrush* as:
*A (normally) straight girl's crush on another girl, often a celebrity. Is mostly platonic in nature. A girl who is girlcrushing must by definition be straight, otherwise it's just a regular crush.*